Twitter not sending email with oauth 2 even after enabling share email on twitter developer dashboard
I’m currently integrating Twitter OAuth 2.0 in my app using Auth0, and I’ve followed the documentation to retrieve the user's email address after successful authentication. However, despite enabling the necessary permissions and setting up Actions in Auth0, the email is not being returned in the response.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Set Up Twitter OAuth 2.0:
I have created an application in Twitter Developer Portal and enabled the required email permission.
I made sure to include openid profile email in the scope during the Auth0 Twitter connection setup.
Created and Deployed Actions:
Since Rules are deprecated, I created a custom Post-Login Action to fetch the email from Twitter using the verify_credentials API endpoint.
The Action runs without errors, but the email is still not returned.
Here is the basic code for the Action I deployed:
const oauth = require('oauth-sign');
const uuid = require('uuid');

exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
  if (event.connectionStrategy !== 'twitter') {
    return;
  }

  const twitterIdentity = event.user.identities.find(identity => identity.provider === 'twitter');
  const oauthToken = twitterIdentity.access_token;
  const oauthTokenSecret = twitterIdentity.access_token_secret;

  const url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json';
  const consumerKey = event.configuration.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY;
  const consumerSecretKey = event.configuration.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY;

  const timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  const nonce = uuid.v4().replace(/-/g, '');

  const params = {
    include_email: true,
    oauth_consumer_key: consumerKey,
    oauth_nonce: nonce,
    oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
    oauth_timestamp: timestamp,
    oauth_token: oauthToken,
    oauth_version: '1.0'
  };

  const oauthSignature = oauth.hmacsign('GET', url, params, consumerSecretKey, oauthTokenSecret);
  params.oauth_signature = oauthSignature;

  const authHeader = Object.keys(params)
    .sort()
    .map((k) => `${k}="${oauth.rfc3986(params[k])}"`)
    .join(', ');

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${url}?include_email=true`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Authorization': `OAuth ${authHeader}` },
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const body = await response.json();
      if (body.email) {
        api.user.setCustomClaim('email', body.email);
      } else {
        console.log('No email returned from Twitter.');
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error('Error retrieving email from Twitter');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching Twitter data:', error);
  }
};

What I’ve Tried:
I’ve ensured that email permissions are enabled for the Twitter app in the Twitter Developer Portal.
I have deployed the Action in Auth0, but the email is still not being returned in the response.
I’ve tested with different Twitter accounts and verified that email is available on the Twitter profile for those users.
Question:
What could be causing the issue where the email is not returned in the response from Twitter OAuth 2.0 despite setting up Actions and ensuring the email permission is enabled?
Additional Information:
Twitter API endpoint: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true
Auth0 connection: Twitter
Auth0 Action: Post-login action to fetch email from Twitter
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

When you authorized the user, did it mention that the app would get access to their email address in the Auth dialog? Do you have a proper Privacy Policy URL and Terms of Service URL set for your app?

@C3roe Yes, I have added privacy URL, Terms of Service URL and it definitely had text "Email will be shrared".
